# deploying next.js JSS app to sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client, jss, nextjs

I have installed sitecore 10.0.3 on premise on dev server (remote desktop) and created next.js Jss app and connected the app with sitecore, now i have the app running and i can access the site from inside remote desktop, also i can access the sitecore CMS from out side the remote desktop but i can not access the site or experience editor for pages from out side the remote deskop.

how shall I deploy the app to make the site public from out side the remote desktop?

note : I am using next self rendering host  loaclhost:3000
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy NextJS to IIS
1- install URLRewrite and IISNode
2- add web.config

```
    <configuration>
  <system.webServer>    
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <iisnode node_env="production" nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe&quot;" interceptor="&quot;%programfiles%\iisnode\interceptor.js&quot;" />

  </system.webServer>
    <location path="" overrideMode="Deny">
        <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp from="">
                <network defaultCredentials="false" host="" password="" port="25" userName="" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

3- add server.js

```
{ createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')
const cors = require('cors');

require('dotenv').config();

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = next({ dev })

const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

const corsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.SITECORE_API_HOST,
};

app.prepare().then(() => {
    
  createServer((req, res) => {
        
        const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
        const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl       
        
        if (pathname === '/a') {
          app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
        } else if (pathname === '/b') {
          app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
        } else {
          handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
        }
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the site via the IP address of your remove desktop network connection. Let's say your IP is `192.168.1.2` - you can access `http://192.168.1.2:3000`.

If you want to use a url with a meaningful name, then add a hosts entry pointing to that IP address, you will still need to add the port to the url. e.g `http://mynextjssite.localhost:3000`

Comment: I have tried this but not working gives me "This page isn’t working  20.216.18.205 didn’t send any data."